# Keystore для подписи приложений

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aide, keystore

За неимением компьютера приходилось писать на смартфоне на `AIDE`. В итоге проект был написан, собран и подписан созданным там же ключом.
Ключ имеется файлом `.keystore`
 При попытке подписать им же прокет в `Android Studio` он выдает список алиасов и выбрав нужный пытается подписать. В итоге кидает ошибку при сборке `No key with alias 'тут мой алиас' found in keystore...`.
Кто знает, что делать?
Создать новый ключ не вариант, т.к. проект уже в Google Play.

Comment: Скорее всего без шансов. Проблема в том что ключ созданный на устройстве изначально храниться в защищенной памяти(чипе) и не подлежит извлечению

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков нет, файл с расширением `.keystore`, им успешно подписываются приложения через `AIDE` на любом из моих устройств

Comment: Тогда добавьте это в вопрос(то что закрытый ключ у вас есть), вопрос я так понимаю переходит из разряда достать с андроида закрытый ключ, в разряд - формат хранения\конвертация ключа

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков подправил, но это было подразумеваемо (наличие у меня ключа, т.к. я попытался им подписать в студии)

Comment: Не с тем уровнем вопросов что тут появляются, сам .keystore я так понимаю к проекту добавлен? Вот этот вопрос на enSO смотрели? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-is-debug-keystore-in-android-studio

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ничего со стака мне не помогло, ни с русского, ни с английского, при проверке через `keytool` кидает исключения после ввода пароля